# When is $\|\boldsymbol A\| \|\boldsymbol A^{-1}\|$ bounded?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms

According to the sub-multiplicative property of (some) matrix norms, we know that

\begin{equation}
\| \boldsymbol I \| \leq \|\boldsymbol A\| \|\boldsymbol A^{-1}\| \ ,
\end{equation}

for some invertible matrix $\boldsymbol A$.

Let $\boldsymbol A(t) = \frac{1}{t}\sum\limits_{s=1}^t \boldsymbol H(s)$ be a positive-definite matrix such that $\boldsymbol H(t)$ is bounded for $t\geq 1$. Given that, I would like to know if

\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \|\boldsymbol A(t)\| \|\boldsymbol A^{-1}(t)\| < \infty \ .
\end{equation}

And out of curiosity, I would also like to know if the term $\|\boldsymbol A\| \|\boldsymbol A^{-1}\|$ **is bounded for all eligible matrices $\boldsymbol A$**.

Comment: What do you mean by eligible? $\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ is bounded for all invertible  matrices.

Comment: If you take $A$ to be $2\times 2$, diagonal, with $n$ and $1/n$ in the diagonal, then $\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ is arbitrarily large (tending to $\infty$ as fast as $n^2$). So, not bounded for all invertible matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you point me for a reference for a proof of that statement? Although my intuition tells me that $\|A\| \|A^{-1}\|$ must be bounded for some $A$, I'm having trouble proving that statement in general.

I said "eligible" to encapsulate all possible matrices $A$ that satisfy the aforementioned property, and not only the specific matrix $A(t)$ that I have defined above.

Comment: user647486: thank you, that's a good counterexample for the general case!

Can you comment on the case with the matrix $A(t)$ defined above? The $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix you picked is not bounded, so your counterexample falls outside the scope of my particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the bounded inverse theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem, the term $\|A\|\|A^-1\|$ is bounded, whenever $A$ is a linear bounded operator that maps from one banach space to another.

Since $A(t) = \sum_{s=1}^tH(s)$ is a finite sum of bounded linear operators, $A(t)$ is also a bounded linear operator. This means that, given $H(s)$ maps from a banach space to another, $\|A\|\|A^-1\|$ is bounded.

In the limit of $t\to\infty$ this probably breaks, since $A(t)$ is no longer guaranteed to be a bounded linear operator, which implies that the bounded inverse theorem might not hold.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Concerning your last sentence, in my case $A(t)$ is multiplied by $1/t$. Therefore, $A(t)\leq H_{\text{max}}$ (where $H_{\text{max}}$ is the bound on each $H(t)$). This means that the bounded inverse theorem holds even as $t \to infty$, right?

Comment: $H(t)$ is bounded, but that does not imply that $\frac{1}{t}\sum_{t=1}^\infty H(t)$ is bounded, since $H(t)$ can grow faster than $t$. If $H(t)$ are such that $A(t)$ is bounded even as $t\to\infty$, then by the limit rule of product also $\lim_{t\to\infty}\|A(t)\|\|A^{-1}(t)\|$ is bounded.